# Can't create a new flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

[image: Error creating project]

I tried creating a new flutter project after updating the android studio and flutter. But after doing it I get this error.

Answer (score 2):

In your project try running `flutter create .` in the terminal

Comment: if that didnt work try it again but run ```flutter clean``` before it.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your RAM and hard-disk space as sometimes low space limits creating new projects.